# How can I set subtitle on QML MediaPlayer?

Tags: qt, qml, qt6, qtmultimedia, qmediaplayer

Subtitle support added to Qt6 Multimedia and we can show a subtitle on MediaPlayer very simple. But I can't use this feature in QML, `setSubtitleText` seems not find in QML or at least not callable.

```
MediaPlayer {
    id: mediaPlayer

    Button{
    onClicked: {
        mediaPlayer.videoOutput.videoSink.setSubtitleText("I'm a subtitle!")
}
}
```

`console.log(mediaPlayer.videoOutput.videoSink)`

> QVideoSink(0x203f364a8b0)

`mediaPlayer.videoOutput.videoSink.setSubtitleText`

> undefined

`mediaPlayer.videoOutput.videoSink.setSubtitleText("some text")`

> TypeError: Property 'setSubtitleText' of object
> QVideoSink(0x203f364a8b0) is not a function

Comment: I think you cant call `setSubtitleText` from QML because it is not `QInvokeable` or `QProperty`. 
 
[Also the docs says:](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html#videoSink-prop)  

> Normal usage of VideoOutput from QML should not require using this property.

Comment: Use [MediaPlayer,subtitleTracks](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html#subtitleTracks-prop) instead.

Comment: @ניר You right, any solution? can I make my own `VideoOutput ` and make that function callable ? I mean by subclassing.

Comment: @folibis I don't get it, that's a read-only property! what's the relation between this getter and my question ?

Comment: @fristhon I think this is a private class and shouldn't be extended because it exists only as an "implementation detail". You can open an issue [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa) though..

Comment: @ניר Thanks I did that and seems will be fixed in next release